# How to use Django - cPanel environment variable

Tags: django, environment-variables, cpanel, environment, production-environment

While setting up a Django app in cPanel, I can assign environment variables. However, I am having trouble using them. For instance, I made an assignment as seen in the picture. But when I use it in my Django application as `os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD_V')`, It doesn't recognize the variable. How can i fix that?

I know there are other methods to do this, but if this method is can be used, I wonder how can it.

Django_Variable_in_cPanel:

[image: Django_Variable_in_cPanel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I set environment variables in CPanel, under Setup Python App, but was not able to locate the variables in my program. Neither in os.environ, nor in the environment object passed in to the application() function. :-/

My hosting provider recommended me using python-dotenv (https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

EDIT: Sorry, @Bedirhandd. My hosting provider were not able to help. It was outside their expertise, unfortunately. To me, it looks like a problem with cPanel itself. I looped over all the environment variables in `os.environ`, and all the variables in the `environment` object that was passed to my application.  None of my custom environment variables that I created in cPanel were present anywhere.

I *did* get it environment variables to work using *python-dotenv*, though.

- I created the file `requirements.txt`, containing the one line `python-dotenv==1.0.1`.
- Under `Python Setup App` i cPanel, I added the requirement.txt as a config file.
- The requirement.txt appeard under `Run Pip Install`. Run this.
- Create the file `.env`, and add a line `DB_EMAIL_PASSWORD_V=MySuperSecretPassord`

Finally, I could run the following:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv 

load_dotenv() 
print(os.environ.get('DB_EMAIL_PASSWORD_V'))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am waiting for your update 